# Is there any way to use IAM as a authentication "method" for PAM?

Tags: security, authentication, pam, amazon-iam

Specifically, running a chain of *postfix*, *dovecot* and *nginx* to provide a "nice" mail service to (not so many) users. All services share [Pluggable authentication module (PAM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) as a possible authentication method. Currently, the system's "passwd" database is being used to auth again via PAM.

[AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) is a hard requirement. Therefore, any other service (like *duosecurity*) is not an option. Before I start to code a PAM module, I'm asking for your experience - how would you do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might not be what you are looking for, but certainly qualifies as a *way to use IAM as a authentication “method” for PAM*:

Denis Mikhalkin's (denismo) [aws-iam-ldap-bridge](https://github.com/denismo/aws-iam-ldap-bridge) *periodically populates the LDAP directory location with the users, groups and roles from AWS IAM*, which will in turn allow to use [libpam-ldap or libpam-ldapd](https://serverfault.com/a/284348/10305) and thereby implicitly *authentication of the Linux users against AWS IAM using their AWS IAM Secret Keys as passwords.*

Please note the following rather significant caveats:

1. *At the moment, the plugin requires a custom version of ApacheDS so manual configuration is unlikely* -  see [Configuring an existing ApacheDS LDAP server](https://github.com/denismo/aws-iam-ldap-bridge/blob/master/INSTALL.md#configuring-an-existing-apacheds-ldap-server)
2. *The default configuration is INSECURE however you are free to alter it to your requirements* - see [Security notes](https://github.com/denismo/aws-iam-ldap-bridge/blob/master/INSTALL.md#security-notes)

#### Personal Assessment

While a native IAM PAM integration would be great (and also enable advanced use cases like [AWS Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA)](http://aws.amazon.com/mfa/)), I like the pragmatic approach to just facilitate the widely used LDAP integration instead - still I would definitely prefer a solution that ideally works with any compliant LDAP server, or at least with a stock [ApacheDS](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/) distribution, in order to ease installation, maintainability and security assessments.